# Pyqt5: How to format text without using QFont?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Well as the title already tells, I want to simply format a text without using `QFont()`. At the moment I'm using it like that:

```
font = QFont()
font.setBold(True)

label = QLabel()
label.setFont(font)
label.setText("Hello World!")
```

So far so good. But if I want to have a certain part in a text of a label bold, it gets quite annoying, because I have to create an extra `QLabel` and use `setBold()` and put this part into the right position. Is there a way (e.g. markdown) to bold a certain part of a text of a label?

Like that:

```
label = QLabel()
label.setText("**Hello** World!")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt uses a subset of HTML for rich text. This is also the default setting. Try:

```
label.setText("<b>Hello</b> World!")
```

The label text format is controlled by the `textFormat` property. The default is Auto, for possible values see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextFormat-enum.

If you use a recent version of Qt (**at least 5.14**) you can also use Markdown as you suggested:

```
label.setTextFormat(Qt.MarkdownText)
label.setText("**Hello** World!")
```

Reference: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html